# Convert 201811 to a date in format yyyymmdd 20181101

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a number field in year month format:

```
201801
201802
201803
etc
```

I would like to convert these to a date, just using the first of the month:

```
20180101
20180201
20180301
etc
```

Went down a stack overflow rabbit hole and tried several things, ended up getting this far before failing:

```
select to_date(concat(cast(cast(201809 as BIGINT) as STRING), "01")) # returns null
```

How can I convert e.g. 201801 to a date being the first of January 2018 in the format yyyymmdd, that's 20180101?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive expects **Date** format as `yyyy-MM-dd` but in your case you are converting `yyyyMMdd` to date datatype, that's the reason why you are getting null value after **to_date**

```
hive> select concat(cast(cast(201809 as BIGINT) as STRING), "01");
+-----------+--+
|    _c0    |
+-----------+--+
| 20180901  |
+-----------+--+
```

**Converting to date:**

```
hive> select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(bigint('201908'),'01'),
'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'));
+-------------+--+
|     _c0     |
+-------------+--+
| 2019-08-01  |
+-------------+--+
```

Comment: Thanks but will this be a date or int data type? End goal is to have this as a date so I can use date functions (e.g. ```months_between()```)

Comment: @DougFir,if we convert to `date type` then we are going to have `Null` values, if we won't convert then it will be treated as same datatype as column defined in the table(i.e.string,bigint..etc).

Comment: @DougFir,as you want to run `months_between()` then you need to change the format of the column to `'yyyy-MM-dd'`(with column data types either string/date) then we can run all built in functions on the columns.